# Sort a JSON array of objects alphabetically along with a property's boolean value in dart

Tags: json, sorting, dart

I have an array of objects like this

```
[
   {
      "contact_id":"ee76f661-91ff-5e6b-b900-79612065a840",
      "contact_name":"Bcd",
      "favorite":false,
   },
   {
      "contact_id":"da34621a-1355-5b6b-8ef5-e3bb60b2c28c",
      "contact_name":"Def",
      "favorite":true,
   },
   {
      "contact_id":"0900bd96-319b-577b-8d01-975347667108",
      "contact_name":"Abcd",
      "favorite":false,
   },
   {
      "contact_id":"0900bd96-319b-577b-8d01-975347667108",
      "contact_name":"Abcde",
      "favorite":true,
   }
]
```

I want to sort the objects alphabetically according to the `contact_name` and those having `favorite` as true should come in the start as well. So, in this case, this is how the sorted array should look like:

```
[
   {
      "contact_id":"0900bd96-319b-577b-8d01-975347667108",
      "contact_name":"Abcde",
      "favorite":true,
   },
   {
      "contact_id":"da34621a-1355-5b6b-8ef5-e3bb60b2c28c",
      "contact_name":"Def",
      "favorite":true,
   },
   {
      "contact_id":"0900bd96-319b-577b-8d01-975347667108",
      "contact_name":"Abcd",
      "favorite":false,
   },
   {
      "contact_id":"ee76f661-91ff-5e6b-b900-79612065a840",
      "contact_name":"Bcd",
      "favorite":false,
   },
]
```

Right now, this is the code that I am using for sorting which is not giving me the required result as I think this method is wrong

```
sortContacts(contacts) {
  contacts.sort((a, b) {
    return a['contact_name']
        .toString()
        .toLowerCase()
        .compareTo(b['contact_name'].toString().toLowerCase());
  });
  contacts.sort((a, b) {
    bool favorite1 = a['favorite'];
    bool favorite2 = b['favorite'];
    return (favorite1 == favorite2) ? 0 : favorite1 ? -1 : 1;
  });
  return contacts;
}
```

I am kind of stuck on this one, any help would be great! Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should do the job:

```
void main() {
  final contacts = [
    {
      "contact_id": "ee76f661-91ff-5e6b-b900-79612065a840",
      "contact_name": "Bcd",
      "favorite": false,
    },
    {
      "contact_id": "da34621a-1355-5b6b-8ef5-e3bb60b2c28c",
      "contact_name": "Def",
      "favorite": true,
    },
    {
      "contact_id": "0900bd96-319b-577b-8d01-975347667108",
      "contact_name": "Abcd",
      "favorite": false,
    },
    {
      "contact_id": "0900bd96-319b-577b-8d01-975347667108",
      "contact_name": "Abcde",
      "favorite": true,
    }
  ];

  contacts.sort((a, b) {
    final aFav = a['favorite'] as bool;
    final bFav = b['favorite'] as bool;

    if (aFav == bFav) {
      final aName = a['contact_name'] as String;
      final bName = b['contact_name'] as String;

      return aName.compareTo(bName);
    } else {
      return aFav ? -1 : 1;
    }
  });

  contacts.forEach(print);
  // {contact_id: 0900bd96-319b-577b-8d01-975347667108, contact_name: Abcde, favorite: true}
  // {contact_id: da34621a-1355-5b6b-8ef5-e3bb60b2c28c, contact_name: Def, favorite: true}
  // {contact_id: 0900bd96-319b-577b-8d01-975347667108, contact_name: Abcd, favorite: false}
  // {contact_id: ee76f661-91ff-5e6b-b900-79612065a840, contact_name: Bcd, favorite: false}
}
```